# Android - efficiently schedule a task periodically?

Tags: android, performance

I've got this code to schedule a task every so often:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable update = new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        try{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    lbl.setText(info);
                    cpb.setProgress(Float.valueOf(textInfo);
                }
            });

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    } 
};
```

I want to constantly update the UI (every second, etc). The code works, however, the interface starts lagging. After the code iterates the task a few times the interface stops responding.

Is there any way I can schedule a task to repeat periodically without overloading the memory and without the interface lagging.

Comment: what you mean by lagging?

Comment: The code runs and the task (which updates the UI) repeats a few times, but as it continually repeats, with each iteration the UI becomes slow and unresponsive.

Comment: get rid of runOnUiThread. how do you call that snippet?

Comment: Why get rid of `runOnUiThread`? I just start it off by doing `handler.postDelayed(update, 1000);`

Comment: I mean, if you that snippet in a method, and run that method multiple times, you have multiple handler. Could be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `lbl` is a `TextView` and `cpb` is a `ProgressBar`, your code will not considerably lag any device as it is. The problem lies somewhere else. Also, you appear to have missed a closing bracket on `(Float.valueOf(textInfo);`.

As an aside, you are unnecessarily using `runOnUiThread` inside the Runnable from what I can see. When you create a `new Handler()` it is implicitly linked to the calling thread's `Looper`, which I am assuming *is the UI thread*. In which case, the `update` Runnable will already be running on the UI thread. EDIT: This should not be the cause of the lag for the record, since iirc `runOnUiThread` checks if it is being executed on the UI thread then just runs it immediately, without doing another post.

Comment: Haha yes, I missed the bracket because this is a completely stripped down version of the code. I don't want to give pages of code.